# How to see which element (of length x) in a list is contained in which other element (of length x+1) of that list?

Tags: r, mapply, combn

Say I have the following list:

```
unlist(mapply(combn, list(1:3), seq_along(1:3), simplify = FALSE), recursive = FALSE)
```

Now, I want to know for each element of length x in the list, in which other elements of length x+1 it is contained. Preferably, it returns a data frame, where the first column gives the index of an element, and the second column gives the index of other elements in which it is contained.

For the example above, it would need to give me:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~a, ~b,
  1,  4,
  1,  5,
  2,  4,
  2,  6,
  3,  5,
  3,  6,
  4,  7,
  5,  7,
  6,  7
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a double `sapply` to compare each pair of vectors in your list. This will return a logical square matrix. If you then call `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` and exclude the diagonal, you will have your desired data frame.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
mylist <- unlist(mapply(combn, list(1:3), seq_along(1:3), simplify = FALSE), 
                 recursive = FALSE)

mat <- which(t(sapply(mylist, function(x) sapply(mylist, function(y) {
  all(x %in% y) & length(y) == length(x) + 1
  }))), arr.ind = TRUE)

setNames(as.data.frame(mat), c("a", "b"))[order(mat[,1]),]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 4
#> 3 1 5
#> 2 2 4
#> 5 2 6
#> 4 3 5
#> 6 3 6
#> 7 4 7
#> 8 5 7
#> 9 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks! It's close to what I'm after. I would like it to only see if an element with length x is contained in an element with size x+1. So row 3, 6 and 9 of your df should not appear. Also, the ordering of values in an element should not matter, such that element 5 of the list (c(1,3)) is also shown to appear in element 7 of the list (c(1,2,3)).

Comment: @Alexander sorry - I misread the question. Hopefully my update fixes that.